# Export large data(million of rows) into CSV in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I have a million of records and I want to export that data into CSV. I used `find_each` method to fetch the records. But it also taking too much time to fetch data and download CSV. I am not able to do other activity in the application because its taking more memory. Its just showing me loading the page in the browser.

I have written the following code in the controller

```
 def export_csv
   require 'csv'          
   lines = []
   csv_vals = []              
   User.where(status:ACTIVE).order('created_atdesc').find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |user|
   csv_vals << user.email if user.email.present?
   csv_vals << user.name if user.name.present?
   .......
   ........
   .......etc
   lines << CSV.generate_line(csv_vals)

   end
   send_data(line, type: 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', \
                      disposition:  "attachment; filename=file123.csv"
 end
```

Is there another way to load the millions of records and download quickly?

Comment: 1. Is this a one-time process that you want to do. Or is this something that you want to expose as a part of a web interface or something so that users can do this anytime?
2. If this is a one-time process, you would be better off exporting directly from the database using command line tools. Which database are you using?

Comment: @ronin 1. It is a part of web interface so that users can do this anytime

Comment: How important is it that the list is 'live'. I could really imagine creating a background job that runs once a day, or every hour or so. If the user wants the list he can download the latest updated version.

Comment: @DeeptiKakade Ideally it would be better if you could move the export logic to a background job that can leverage the power of the database command line. You could probably re-direct the user to another page that polls the status of this job or something of that sort and let him download the file once the background job has completed exporting.

Comment: This is also a nice article about handling large data sets in rails https://tylertringas.com/very-large-csv-import-in-rails-on-heroku/

Answer (score 1):

this may help:
[genereating and streaming potentially large csv files using ruby on rail](http://smsohan.com/blog/2013/05/09/genereating-and-streaming-potentially-large-csv-files-using-ruby-on-rails/)